# Is this copy constructor a bad idea?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

So, I have the feeling that this is a bad idea:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const Foo& from)
  {
     memcpy(this, &from, sizeof(Foo));

     m_someData = new int[m_dataLength];
     memcpy(m_someData, from.m_someData, m_dataLength * sizeof(int));
  }

  private:
    int* m_someData;
    int m_dataLength;

};
```

The question is: why? If the `memcpy` parameters are the same type (and size), with identical layout, where's the bad?

One potential issue I see is if there is a `string` or `vector<>` field, but I'm not sure if that's a valid concern.

Comment: Any member that's a pointer will only be a shallow copy.

Comment: Obviously this implementation cannot perform a deep copy.

Comment: Why you would want to do this, since the already defined copy constructor by the compiler would do the same job only much much safer?

Comment: It is bad because unnecessary code is bad. Unless you get paid by lines of code.

Comment: Okay, modified example.

Comment: Still too much code. You can remove the `memcpy` line. The class is empty.

Comment: What about the virtual pointer of polymorphic objects? Wouldn't they be destroyed?

Comment: Asked by a member with a rep of 17k? are you deliberately trolling the community? it's a terrible idea unless the class is a POD, in which case it's un-necessary.

Comment: @juanchopanza Modified to require a  deep copy of an array field.

Comment: For one, `memcpy` is almost always wrong in C++. There are far better tools available, including the default copy constructor and `std::copy`.

Comment: @RichardHodges Okay, I'm deleting my not-quite-polite comment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidLively really not a problem. I don't ask for politeness, merely correctness. There is no place for polite incorrectness in mission-critical systems. :)

Comment: @RichardHodges On that we agree!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `Foo` can be derived from, consider what happens when you have a `Bar` class derived from `Foo`, and copy-construct a `Foo` from that `Bar` instance.

If you have any virtual methods, your `sizeof(Foo)` includes any information added by the compiler to implement virtual methods (meaning the vtable), which you definitely don't want to copy.

If you don't have any virtual methods, but `Bar` adds a field to `Foo`, then you still have a potential problem: that field can be stored in the padding bytes of `Foo`. They would be clobbered by a `memcpy`.

Finally:

> One potential issue I see is if there is a `string` or `vector<>` field, but I'm not sure if that's a valid concern.

Why wouldn't it be? It would clearly break, and it would break badly.

---

You can avoid this problem by using the default automatically generated copy constructor. If you want to add logic to that, and not be forced to mention all fields you want to copy, use a hidden data container:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const Foo& from)
  {
     m_Data = from.m_Data;

     m_Data.m_someData = new int[m_Data.m_dataLength];
     memcpy(m_Data.m_someData, from.m_Data.m_someData, m_Data.m_dataLength * sizeof(int));
  }

  private:
    struct Data {
      int* m_someData;
      int m_dataLength;
      // more fields
    };
    Data m_Data;

};
```

Note how `m_Data = from.m_Data;` here has the exact effect you were trying to achieve with the `memcpy`, except it does it safely.

Comment: THAT is a good answer, and really cleared things up. Thank you.

Comment: The private `Data` struct nicely solves what I was asking, but it *initially* seemed like an unnecessary extra hoop through which to jump. However, the vtable, etc. makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

why it's wrong:

```
struct boom1 {
  boom1(const boom1& from) 
  // reason 1: not using an initialisation list means double-initialisation of members. inefficient.
  {
    // reason 2: undefined behaviour on all subsequent access to
    // this->_s or from._s after this line
    memcpy(this, &from, sizeof(from));

    // reason 3: what if someone derived from this class? didn't you just overwrite the RTTI info pointer??
  }

  // reason 4: c++ already generates a copy constructor that does the right thing automatically. why are you laying mines for other developers?

  std::string _s;
}
```

"yes but my particular class is a POD and I'm in control of it"...

... until someone else derives from it, modifies it or tries to maintain it.

no, no, no. This is never right. always wrong. make sure your student understands this. One day he may be programming a google car. You wouldn't want it to run over your kids now would you?

Comment: By all means. Double check my claim about the RTTI pointer before you put it on a screen. That part is very much implementation defined.